# Computing the best-fit plane normal from n points

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I've been working steadily through "3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development" and am stuck on how the authors derived their equation for the best-fit plane normal given n points. Please note, I'm not necessarily looking for someone to derive the proof, a good book/reference/technique name would suffice.

I'll describe the problem but for a quick view, see section 9.5.3:
https://gamemath.com/book/geomprims.html#plane_best_fit

Given $n$ points, $p_1 = [x_1, y_1, z_1], [x_2, y_2, z_2], ..., [x_n, y_n, z_n]$

The normal $x,y,z$ components are as follows but with no explanation of derivation.

$n_x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n(z_i + z_{i+1})(y_i - y_{i+1})$

A similar equation is given for each component of the normal vector.

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated your post to LaTeX, please see that it is correct. `:)`

Comment: @gekkostate, you are the boss!!! Never heard of LaTex but what a difference it makes. I made a few changes too. Thank you!

Comment: You can learn more about it here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal: Plucker and others of his generation figured out that if you took a polygon in space and projected it down to the xy-plane, you could compute the area $A_{xy}$ of the resulting polygon. And the same goes for $A_{zy}$ and $A_{zx}$. In fact, you can compute the *signed* area, so that counterclockwise polygons are counted as positive and clockwise ones are negative. The formula for $n_z$ that you've got is exactly twice the formula for the area $A_{xy}$. I'll come back to that in a minute.

The cool thing is that these three projected areas, when assembled into a vector, turn out to produce the vector normal to the polygon. This is pretty easy to see when the polygon is parallel to one of the planes: two of the projected areas are zero, and the third's nonzero. For the more general case, the quickest proof I know involves some linear algebra and the change-of-area formula for double integrals, and I don't want to write it out here.

Let's go back to the planar area question: WHY is that the right formula (except for the missing factor of $\dfrac{1}{2}$)?

Answer:

First of all, let's consider the case where there are just 3 points.  Since every polygon can be broken into a collection of triangles, that'll do the job.

Second, if you subtracted some number $c$ from all the $y$-coordinates, the number you got wouldn't change. Same goes for $z$-coordinates. So let's subtract $z_1$ from all the $z$ coords, adn $y_1$ from all the $y$-coords. Now we've got a triangle with one vertex at the origin. The other two verts are $(y_1 -y_0, z_1 - z_0)$ and $(y_2 - y_0, z_2 - z_0)$. And if you know about cross products of vectors, you can work out that the area of the triangle is just the cross product of the two edge-vectors (up to a factor of $\dfrac{1}{2}$).

The usual version of the cross-product formula for area has an absolute value so that you get the area....but if you remove the absolute value, you get the *signed* area, which is exactly what you need in Plucker's formula for the normal. It's a win-win thing!

Shameless plug: this is worked out in detail in the graphics book I just finished writing. But I believe that I'm not supposed to say what book that is.

One additional bit of trivia: If you computed the normal vector for your set of point by just taking vectors between 3 of the points (say $AB$ and $AC$) and finding the cross product, that'd work, most of the time. But if $A$, $B$, and $C$ happened to be collinear, you'd get the $0$-vector as an answer, and have to   try again. Furthermore, the Plucker method has the charm that if the points all *almost* lie in a plane, but happen to have suffered roundoff error or something, the method still produces a very good approximation to the plane normal. In fact, if the points are perturbed uniformly and independently along the true normal, I think that the computed Plucker normal may have an expected value that's the true normal, under some weak assumputions about the distribution of original points, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Thanks John. Just one comment, I don't think we need to divide by 2 as long as we're consistent about it ... that would mean our normal vector is just twice the magnitude but still in the right direction.That aside, I kinda follow what you mean about subtracting and setting one of the verts to the origin but I'm going to need a little more. If you can't name the book can you give your full name? Does this site have private messaging?? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Instead, I'm going to suggest two books by the competition: Pete Shirley and Steve Marchner's "Computer Graphics" (might be "intro to computer graphics" or something like that) and Akenine-Moller, Haines and Hoffman's "Real Time Rendering." You can also contact me by email -- I'm a prof. of computer science at Brown University, and lead author on a new graphics text. That should let you find me. :)